# Javascript image fade?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fade

I have a basic JavaScript image slideshow which loops through 4 images with a 5 second delay.

Is there any way to make each image fade in as opposed to just appearing instantly? Perhaps using the css3 transition effects??

I don't want to use any pre-made slideshow addons or anything, I am trying to make this myself out of just JavaScript.

[Here is a codepen link](http://codepen.io/caedanlavneder/pen/gwzav)

Thanks in advance

Comment: CSs opacity, jquery fade, nivoslider

Comment: Here is another example that you can look at and easily adapt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278147/javascript-fade-div-in-on-button-click-then-on-2nd-button-click-fade-out/16278829#16278829

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go: as talked about in previous comments. A jsFiddle that does what you want in Jquery.
http://jsfiddle.net/HhpW5/5/
You asked specifically how to change between the divs
I do that in this demo simply by using the XOR bitwise operator and concatenating to the prefix: "demo" resulting in: "demo0" or "demo1"

```
  toggle^=1;
```

Everything else is pretty self explanatory with my comments. Hope this helps.

Comment: How strange, "I don't want to use any pre-made slideshow addons or anything, I am trying to make this myself out of just JavaScript." And a jquery answer selected?

Comment: We decided in the comments to go with a jquery solution. But, just for you here is the same example in pure javascript form: http://jsfiddle.net/A74vQ/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

[See Transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transition)

[Play around with transtions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions)

```
#demo {
  background: #969696;
  width: 400px;
  height:300px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: verdana;
  -webkit-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms; /* property duration timing-function delay */
    -moz-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    -o-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt make any difference where did you test it?

Comment: Check this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FLmje. It doesnt switch abruptly.. You get a little bit of easing effect...

Comment: How odd, it works in chrome but not in firefox even though you inlcuded "-moz-"

Comment: Chrome's behavior isn't correct according to spec (though I wish it was!). You'd need two separate elements to perform a cross-fade in a valid way.

Comment: So i need to have four seperate divs and just switch to each of those as per image in the slideshow?

Comment: You just need 2 separate divs, alternate which one you load to and then do the crossfade.

Comment: @Duopixel Yes i just now saw that since it doesn't know about when BG is gng to get switched...

Comment: Probably with a single div and using jquery to fade in and fadeout and in the callback switching the bacground in a cycle should work....

Comment: With regards to nullSharp's idea, is there a way to get javascript to toggle between to divs, kind of like and if and else statement but with less code??

Comment: You can do a few things, I would also suggest just using jquery for the transitions. Might make life a bit easier. I'll make a demo real quick...

Comment: I agree with @nullSharp with jquery you dont need to worry about custom transition effect yo uget all effect with fadeIn, fadeOut , delay and in callback images can be switched...

Comment: Demo is all set added an answer below, but just in case. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/HhpW5/5/